# Find dead nodes from Parent Child Node collection

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I have a collection of custom node that has a parent child relation. Each node can be a composite type (that has other child in it) or a simple type (leaf level node)

I want to write a function that will be give me list of all dead nodes.
For example here is the node collection

[image]

Based on the above case, p2, p3, p8, p9, p10, p6, c1 are dead nodes (since down their hierarchy they don't have any simple node in them)

I need a function as

```
private List<NodeEntity> GetDeadNodes(List<NodeEntity> originalList)
```

Here is the function for has the original list

```
private List<NodeEntity> GetOriginalList()
{
    var list = new List<NodeEntity>()
    {
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P1", ParentCode = "001", Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "C1", ParentCode = "001", Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P2", ParentCode = "P1", Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P3", ParentCode = "P2", Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P8", ParentCode = "P3", Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P9", ParentCode = "P3", Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P4", ParentCode = "P1", Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "L3", ParentCode = "P1",  Type = NodeType.Simple},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P6", ParentCode = "P1",  Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P10", ParentCode = "P4",  Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "L2", ParentCode = "P4",  Type = NodeType.Simple},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "P5", ParentCode = "P4",  Type = NodeType.Composite},
        new NodeEntity() {Code = "L1", ParentCode = "P5",  Type = NodeType.Simple}
    };
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Are p1, p4, p6, L3, c1 at the same level?

Comment: What have you tried? Tree plus recursive depth first search? Queue of nodes to visit starting from Simple ones? Anything?

Comment: see my image attachment. p6, p4, L3 are children of p1. c1 and p1 are at the same level that are children of 001

Comment: ...and p2? Their positioning is slightly throwing me off.

Comment: p2 is a child of p1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that.

```
    private List<NodeEntity> GetDeadNodes(List<NodeEntity> originalList)
    {
        var rest = originalList.ToList();

        // Remove simple nodes and their ascendants.
        // The rest will be dead nodes.
        var simpleNodes = originalList.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.Simple);
        foreach (var simpleNode in simpleNodes)
        {
            rest.Remove(simpleNode);
            RemoveAscendants(rest, simpleNode);
        }

        return rest;
    }

    private void RemoveAscendants(List<NodeEntity> rest, NodeEntity node)
    {
        var parent = rest.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Code == node.ParentCode);

        // We have reached the root node.
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        rest.Remove(parent);
        RemoveAscendants(rest, parent);
    }
```

Comment: (i) Why use recursion for what is a simple `while` loop? `while node != null { remove node; node = find parent node;}`
(ii) the comment should be "we have reached the root node OR the parent node has already been removed"

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a simple scan up the tree from each Simple node to collect all the nodes to keep (in pseudo code):

```
put Simple nodes in a Set

while node in Set
  add node to a 'seen' list
  add parent to Set

dead nodes = all nodes except 'seen' nodes
```